# How useful is it to test the significance of the residual deviance by comparing to the saturated model?

Tags: statistical-significance, generalized-linear-model, deviance

I'm reading the lecture notes of Germán Rodríguez on GLM (http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes), and I'm a little puzzled why the author keeps testing the residual deviance of a model, say $X_1$, by comparing to the saturated model $\Omega = X_1 + X_2$. That is, the null hypothesis is
\begin{equation}
H_0: \beta_{X_2} = 0,
\end{equation}
where $\beta_{X_2}$ are the parameters in the model $X_2$. The test statistic in this case is the difference in deviance, which is simply the residual deviance of $X_1$
\begin{align}
d &= D(X_1) - D(X_1 + X_2) \\
&= D(X_1) - D(\Omega) \\
&= D(X_1) \\
&\sim \chi^2_{n-p_1}
\end{align}
since $D(\Omega) = 0$, and $n$ is the number of observations and $p_1$ the number of parameters in our model of intereset $X_1$. So whenever $d$ is significant, the author rejects the null hypothesis, and concludes that "the model $X_1$ does not fit the data".

Would you agree that this is a redundant conclusion? Of course, comparing to the saturated model, no other model fits the data. So when is such a test really useful? What am I missing?